# How to paginate or infinite scroll by number of items in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

**Requirement**

1. On start 20 items will be loaded.
2. When user scrolls to end, 20 more items will be loaded.

**Problem**
Firestore Query has `startAt()` and `endAt()` methods which works on value of `OrderBy` field. I want something to work on index.

```
interface Product{
   price:number;
}
```

Suppose there are 100 products for 20$ and 30 products for 10$.
First load can be fetched

```
query
.orderBy(price,desc)
.limitTo(20)
```

Now price of last item is 20$. To load next 20 results

```
query
.orderBy(price,desc)
.startAt(20$)
.limitTo(20)
```

It will return the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should "use a document snapshot to define the query cursor" as explained in the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor

Therefore you would do as follows:

```
var first = db.collection("....").orderBy("price", "desc").limit(20);

return first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
  // Get the last visible document
  var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
  console.log("last", lastVisible);

  // Construct a new query starting at this document,
  // Get the next 20 cities.
  var next = db.collection("....")
          .orderBy("price", "desc")
          .startAfter(lastVisible)
          .limit(20);
});
```